# Processing an updated search form

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I have a page that renders data a user searched for. I would like to allow the user to change search credentials at any time on the side of the page. For some reason, It is only working for the 'change school' part. Why is the code never reaching the other search fields (when I change the search type for example, nothing happens, nothing prints to console). Please ignore the indentation errors, it got messed up while pasting it in!

Relevant HTML: (all the names/id's for text fields match those in the python code for sure)

```
<form id="update" name="update" method="post" action="/find-it/">
<input type="submit" value="search" id="enter" form="update">
```

PYTHON:

```
        if request.method == 'POST':

        if "updateSchool" in request.form:
            print('school changed')
            school = request.form['updateSchool']
            data = updateSchool(school)

            return render_template('testBrowse.html', data=data)

        elif "updateType" in request.form:
            print('type changed')
            newType = request.form['updateType']

            data = updateType(newType)

            print('getting to update type')

            return render_template('testBrowse.html', data=data)

        elif "updateTitle" in request.form:
            print('title changed')

            newTitle request.form['updateTitle']

            data = updateTitle(newTitle)

            return render_template('testBrowse.html', data=data)

    return render_template('testBrowse.html', data=data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I see is that there are no updateSchool, updateType, or updateTitle input elements in the form html you posted.

If we assume that all three of them exist in the same form, you will never get past the first if block.

```
if "updateSchool" in request.form:
```

Checks to see if the field exists in the form that was posted, not if it is populated.  So it will always evaluate true.  You may want to use this instead:

```
if request.form['updateSchool']:
```

This will evaluate true only if the updateSchool field is populated.

Also, you do not need the multiple calls to

```
return render_template('testBrowse.html', data=data)
```

You can just leave the one at the bottom.  Regardless of what happens in the code above, it is always returning the same template and data.